# Checking if an entity matches user-specified filters saved on a model

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables

```
Users(id, ...)
Groups(id, filters[])
Trackings(id, user_id, field, boolean_value, string_value, integer_value, date_value)
```

Each user has an arbitrary number of `trackings`, each recording some user defined attribute for that user. And where Group's filters is a JSONB array of objects of the form `filter(field, type, value)

Example of a group's filters

```
{field: sessions, type: greater_than, value: 1}
{field: orders, type: is, value: 5}
```

Say for a given user, I want to find all the groups that match said user. What the best way to do this?

Or for a given group, I want to find all matching users

Is this possible?

Comment: Just to be sure: Is the `field` column of the `Trackings` table what links it to the `Groups` table?

Comment: Np, there's no explicit link between groups and trackings/visitors. The link is if they match the filters